# Line wrapping inside tabular

Tags: tabularx, minipage

Is there a way to parametrize `tabular` such that in the example given, it typesets as for `minipage`? In particular, line wrapping in the second cell.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{.45\textwidth}@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}}
  \lipsum[1][1]
  &
    \lipsum[1][2]
\end{tabular*}\par

\subsection*{minipage}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1][1]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}\end{minipage}
%\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\textwidth} % A
\begin{minipage}[t][]{0.45\textwidth} % B
  \lipsum[1][2]
  \vspace*{\fill} % B (cont.)
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you used `l` for the second column which forces single line. Use a `p` column as you have in the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{%
    @{}%
    p{.45\textwidth}%
    @{\extracolsep{1em}}%
    p{.45\textwidth}%
    @{}%
  }
  \lipsum[1][1]
  &
  \lipsum[1][2]
\end{tabular*}\par

\subsection*{minipage}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1][1]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}\end{minipage}
%\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\textwidth} % A
\begin{minipage}[t][]{0.45\textwidth} % B
  \lipsum[1][2]
  \vspace*{\fill} % B (cont.)
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```